# what vowels is the gemora trying to replace the word ּיִקְנְוּ with יִקָנו or יַׁקְנו

Tags: grammar-dikduk, daf-yomi

I was learning with my chavrusa i used the Hebrew artscroll and he used the English version we bumped into [this gemora](http://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.9a.51?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all/),

הכא כתיב (דברים כב, יג) כי יקח בבעל תלה רחמנא
התם נמי כתיב (ירמיהו לב, מד) *שדות בכסף יקנו*
**קרי ביה יקנו**
מאי טעמא קרית ביה יקנו משום דכתיב ומכר ה"נ קרי ביה כי יקח

what vowels is the gemora trying to replace the word ּיִקְנְוּ with it יִקָנו or יַׁקְנו
In the English version it was spelled ּ**יַקְנו** ּand the Hebrew version was spelled ּ**יִקָנו** which one is correct and does it at all make a difference

Comment: Yikanu seems to be a mistaken copying of Yikkanu in 32:15.

Comment: see verse 15 and 43, and understand the meaning of th e Drasha. I thing that Chachomim have some flexibility for the drasha and in Gemoro it is permitted to say YIkanu

Comment: If you saw the verse but think the _g'mara_ may have different vowels and are therefore asking, then that info should be in your question post, so people can address it in answers. These comments here are ephemeral by design and will not last.

Comment: I don't know why you think the Gemara is replacing anything. It's just saying that the Tanakh applies the root ק.נ.ה. "to buy" to the process of sale, so you shouldn't think that the Torah only thinks of sales as related to the seller (and thereby explain why a Shtar Mechira is given by the Mocheir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: probably *yaknu*, but it doesn't matter.

The *gemara* is comparing *kiddushin* to the sale of a field, where in the latter case the two parties are a seller and a buyer, and in the former, the groom and the bride's father (in the case of an under-age bride).  The *gemara* claims that the active agent in the sale of a field is the seller, since the verse  says ומכר, *and he [the seller] sells*, whereas the active agent in *kiddushin* is the groom, since the verse states כי יקח, *when he [the groom] takes*.

The *gemara* then brings a refutation from another verse that flips the agent around for the sale of a field, namely Jeremiah 32:44, which has the words יקנו, *they will buy*.  The *gemara* retorts that we actually read this as יַקנוּ (*yaknu*), *they will sell*.  This brings the agency back to the seller.  If we were to read יִקָּנוּ (*yikkanu*), *they will be bought*, the agency would be unclear.  Indeed, the *Maharsha* on this *sugya* confirms that we chose the correct vowels, and explains: הוא מקנה השדה לקונה, *he [the seller] sells [makneh] the field to the buyer*.

However, lack of clarity of the agency would be enough to invalidate the *gemara*'s refutation from this verse, and so it seems not to matter how we read it<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> The rest of the *sugya* is also no proof, for if in the *gemara*'s subsequent attempt to re-read יִקַּח (*yikkakh*), we were to make an analogy to the above and read a *hifil* form, *ie.* יַקֵּח (*yakkeykh*), we would find that we have created a conjugation that is not attested in *Tanakh*: much better would be to read the *hofal* form יֻקַּח (*yukkakh*).  Thus, it is difficult to compare the two re-readings to say they have been changed to the same *binyan*.